# how to find the max index of a string from variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, maxlength

suppose i have a string as

```
        string[] _strFile;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listview1.Items)
        {
            string _strRecFileName = item.SubItems[5].Text;
            _strFile = _strRecFileName.Split('\\');
        }
```

in my listview i have a string as \123\abc\hello\.net\****winxp****
now i want to get the last value of the string i.e. **winxp** in this case..
what is the function to do that?

can i use getupperbond function to calculate the upper bound of the string and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] files = _strRecFileName.Split('\\');
string lastElement = files[files.Length - 1];
```

Of course, if you're dealing with actual filenames and paths and stuff, it's probably easier to just use the `Path` class:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(_strRecFileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

why not to use

```
string expectedPart = Path.GetFileName(item.SubItems[5].Text);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string s = @"a\b\c\d\e";
int index = s.LastIndexOf('\\');
string fileName = s.Substring(index + 1);
```

You will only create one extra string in this case so it will use less memory than an array of strings. But as codeka said if the text is a proper path then the `Path` class would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "\\123\\abc\\hello\\.net\\winxp";
String[] tokens = str.Split('\\');
String lastToken = tokens[tokens.Length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String lastArrayItem = _strFile[_strFile.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regex

```
string sub = System.Text.Regularexpressions.Regex.Match(TextVar,@"\\(\w+?)$").groups[1].value
```